# Create an array for single values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3, I'm trying to compare the values via "function(d)" but they are coming in as single boolean values and while I can turn them into arrays with a single value, I can't loop through them to make the comparison I need.

Currently, d.cause updates the fill color of the 'rect' when true but if none are true, then I need to state that in a message. I've tried to compare checking if each "d3.selectAll('rect')" contains a particular class but it won't tell me if ALL of them contain it because they come in as separate values.

```
let dataset = [   
    {
        "scene": "IR0006426320",
        "scene_start_time": "2018-02-05T15:03:30",
        "chips": [
            {
                "chip": "2018.02.05.150",
                "start_date": "2018-02-05T00:05:07",
                "end_date": "2018-02-05T01:26:23",
                "co_num": ["Potentially Unauthorized"
                ],
                "cause": false
            }
]
```

---

```
d3.select(".cause")
    .on("click", function() {

        rects.selectAll("rect") 
        .style("fill", function(d){

            let newB = d.cause;
            let newA = [];


            if (newB === false){
                newA.push(newB);
            }

            console.log(newA);


        });

        $( ".cause" ).toggleClass( "default viewCause" );
    });`
```

What I need to do is compare all values for "d.cause" and if ALL are false, then generate a message.

The code above displays this in the console:

> data.js:748 [false]
>
> data.js:748 [false]
>
> data.js:748 [false]
>
> data.js:748 []
>
> data.js:748 [false]
>
> data.js:748 []
>
> data.js:748 [false]
>
> data.js:748 [false]

What I'd like to see is:

> [false, false, false, false, false, false]

Comment: So the `console.log` is called 8 times with different zero/single-element arrays?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: move `newA` declaration out of the function, because right now it is overriden on every `style("fill", ...)` call

Comment: Checking if all are false is logically equivalent to the complement of checking if at least one is true. That's what you're doing. Except instead of `toggleClass`, you probably want to `addClass`.

Comment: The "toggleClass" is working and doing something a bit different as it has to do with a button click. I really need to compare those values but they come in as separate values in regard to their 'rect', if that makes sense. I've removed the "toggleClass" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just show the message, and hide it in the little `if` you removed.

Comment: Thanks all! I may need to rewrite some of this...